# How to reformat existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, pivot, crosstable

I have following dataframe in python:

| geographical area | area deep indoor | pop deeep indoor | area indoor | pop indoor | area incar | pop incar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| B | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| C | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |

and the idea is to convert it somehow to this:

| deep indoor | area | pop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |
| B | 7 | 8 |
| C | 13 | 14 |

| indoor | area | pop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 3 | 4 |
| B | 9 | 10 |
| C | 15 | 16 |

| incar | area | pop |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 6 |
| B | 11 | 12 |
| C | 17 | 18 |

I really don't see any way doing this. I'm lost :-)
Any ideas or links to possible solutions are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

just use loc to select the columns you need and rename the geography column for each of the three cases. you need them as three separate DF, per your question

```
df.loc[:,['geographical area','area deep indoor','pop deep indoor']].rename(columns={'geographical area': 'deep indoor'})
```

```
    deep indoor     area deep indoor    pop deep indoor
0   A   1   2
1   B   7   8
2   C   13  14
```

```
df.loc[:,['geographical area','area indoor','area indoor']].rename(columns={'geographical area': 'indoor'})
```

```
indoor  area indoor     area indoor
0   A   3   3
1   B   9   9
2   C   15  15
```

```
df.loc[:,['geographical area','area incar','pop incar']].rename(columns={'geographical area': 'incar'})
```

```
    incar   area incar  pop incar
0   A   5   6
1   B   11  12
2   C   17  18
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought to have all in 1 big dataframe , but with this I could basically obtain the same result!

Comment: @Moose  Not following you.  From question I understood that there is a wide data frame and you need a way to slice it out into multiple data frames, hence the proposed solution. Does this didn’t answer the question?